# Best way to draw a rope in sprite-kit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am playing around with Sprite-Kit and making some games for fun. Right now i am making **Rope'n Fly-ish game**. A character is swinging from building to building spiderman-style and if he touches the ground its game over.

I have a good idea on how to make everything except the "rope". After some googling i have found SKShapeNode, and how to draw it:

```
SKShapeNode *yourline = [SKShapeNode node];
CGMutablePathRef pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, 100.0, 100.0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, 50.0, 50.0);
yourline.path = pathToDraw;
[yourline setStrokeColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self addChild:yourline];
```

1. Ho do i set the start-point from the characters current position?
2. What is the easiest way to make it wiggle a little? Like a real rope would do?

Will try to answer any unclear parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can use your character's position property to define the start point:

```
SKShapeNode *yourline = [SKShapeNode node];
CGMutablePathRef pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, yourCharacter.position.x, yourCharacter.position.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, 50.0, 50.0);
yourline.path = pathToDraw;
[yourline setStrokeColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self addChild:yourline];
```

2) Maybe take a look at this: https://github.com/mraty/spritekit-ropes

Comment: Wow, that seems to be an awesome repository! Thank you for the link!